# Generic constraint for Constructor with string argument?

Tags: c#, generics, c#-2.0, constraints, filehelpers

How to create a generic class that allows types which has constructor taking one string argument and implements ToString and implements Two functions as below.

```
    class Convert<T>:ConverterBase
        where T:new()
    {

        public override object StringToField(string from)
        {
            try
            {
                return new T(from);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException exception)
            {
                ThrowConvertException(from, exception.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }

        public override string FieldToString(object from)
        {
            return from.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Note:
ConvertBase is a abstract class in FileHelpers csv reader library. I already have classes that corresponds to my fields in csv, didn't want to create seperate Classes that inherit ConvertBase inorder to use with the FileHelpres library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there you can create a base class that stores the converter function and implements both members, after that you can inherit from it and only provide the string to object convertion

```
public abstract class Convert<T>:ConverterBase
{
    private Func<string, T> ConverterFunction {get;set;}

    protected Convert(Func<string, T> converterFunction)
    {
        ConverterFunction = converterFunction;
    }

    public override object StringToField(string from)
    {
        try
        {
            return ConverterFunction(from);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException exception)
        {
            ThrowConvertException(from, exception.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public override string FieldToString(object from)
    {
        return from.ToString();
    }

}
```

Later create some simple derived classes for example:

```
public class ConvertMyClass:ConverterBase<MyClass>
{
    public ConvertMyClass()
        :base(from => new MyClass(from)
    { 
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :) Remember to download the last stable version from: 
http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewLog.html?buildId=lastSuccessful&buildTypeId=bt66&tab=artifacts&guest=1

**EDIT: Using Reflection you can try:**

```
class Convert<T>:ConverterBase
{

    public override object StringToField(string from)
    {
        try
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), from);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException exception)
        {
            ThrowConvertException(from, exception.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public override string FieldToString(object from)
    {
        return from.ToString();
    }

}
```

NOTE: Reflection is slow, so you must take that into account

Comment: My intention is to completely eliminating classes like this ConvertMyClass, provided the Type T has a constructor with one string argument so that I can use  `[FieldConverter(typeof(Convert<HasRequiredFns>))]`

Comment: @yesraaj: So you need to use reflection to get the constructor with one argument string and dynamicaly call it using Activator, I just updated the anwser

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to use the constructor constraint (`new()`) to constrain to anything other than an empty constructor.  One way to work around this though is to use a lambda expression.  For example

```
class Convert<T>:ConverterBase {
  private Func<string, T> _factory;
  public (Func<string, T> factory) {
    _factory = factory;
  }

  public override object StringToField(string from) {
    try {
      return _factory(from);
    } ...
  }
}
```

Now I can create instances of `Convert<T>` and use a lambda expression to forward to the constructor of the type

```
new Convert<Foo>(s => new Foo(s));
```

**EDIT** C# 2.0 implementation since the OP is stuck with 2.0

```
public delegate TResult Func<T, TResult>(T arg);

new Convert<Foo>(delegate (string s) { return new Foo(s); });
```

Comment: I am stuck with c#2.0, I think I can't use Func<>

Comment: Its just a delegate. Create it yourself: `public delegate TResult Func<out TResult>()`

Comment: @yesraaj You can just define `Func<>` yourself and use the old C# delegate style syntax.  I updated my answer with an example

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can only create a constraint that enforces, that your class has a *parameterless constructor*. The constraint for that is `new()`, as you know.

`ToString()` is available on every type, because it is defined on `Object` and every type inherits from `Object`. However, you can't know or enforce, whether your type provides it's own implementation of `ToString()`.

To make sure, the type parameter implements two specific methods, put them into an interface and constrain the type parameter to that interface and make your class implement that interface.